# Sending status updates through helper function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have the following screen where I call a helper function `pouchDB_helper.sync()` to gather a bunch of data for me.

The goal is to be able to record where in the function it is currently at so I can give a percent or a status update in my `render()`

I'm new to react / react-native so I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about doing it. I'd like to be able to keep it as a helper function if possible because I use this function in other areas, this is just the only place I actually need a status update on where it's at in the process.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, AsyncStorage, Button, StatusBar, Text, StyleSheet, View, } from 'react-native';
import * as pouchDB_helper from '../utils/pouchdb';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: "5%",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    width:"100%"
  },
  statusHeader: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "600",
    marginBottom: 10,
    textAlign:'center',
    width:'100%'
  }
});

type Props = {};
export default class SyncScreen extends Component<Props> {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Syncing Settings',
  };

  render() {

    pouchDB_helper.sync().then((response) => {
      //IT'S DONE
    }, (error) => { alert("THERE WAS AN ERROR"); });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.statusHeader}>Syncing, please wait..</Text>
        <Text>WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE TEXT</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

---

### **pouchDB_helper** example

**note:** This is just an example. I know the `.get()` won't take long enough to warrant a status but I'm just trying to understand the concept.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-react-native'

export async function sync() {

    const company_id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('company_id');
    const device_db = new PouchDB(company_id, {auto_compaction: true});

    //STATUS UPDATE 1

    return device_db.get("settings").then((s) => {

      //STATUS UPDATE 2

      return device_db.get("get_this").then((s) => {

        //STATUS UPDATE  3

        return device_db.get("get_that").then((s) => {

          //STATUS UPDATE 4

        }, (error) => { return false; });

      }, (error) => { return false; });

    }, (error) => { return false; });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach would be passing a function to the sync function which can change the state and set the desired text on component.

**Example**

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    level: 'some init value'
  };
}

onChangeState = (level) => {
  this.setState({level});
}

componentDidMount() {
  pouchDB_helper.sync(this.onChangeState).then((response) => {
    //IT'S DONE
    this.onChangeState('Finished');
  }, (error) => { alert("THERE WAS AN ERROR"); });
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.statusHeader}>Syncing, please wait..</Text>
      <Text>{`Current level is ${this.state.level}`}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

---

```
export async function sync(changeState) {

    const company_id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('company_id');
    const device_db = new PouchDB(company_id, {auto_compaction: true});

    //STATUS UPDATE 1
    changeState(1);
    return device_db.get("settings").then((s) => {

      //STATUS UPDATE 2
      changeState(2);
      return device_db.get("get_this").then((s) => {

        //STATUS UPDATE  3
        changeState(3);
        return device_db.get("get_that").then((s) => {

          //STATUS UPDATE 4
          changeState(4);
        }, (error) => { return false; });

      }, (error) => { return false; });

    }, (error) => { return false; });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm still trying to figure out the scope of what functions are available where so this is interesting! However I am getting the error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.level')`

Comment: @bryan you need to init the state value on constructor. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for this, that seemed to solve that error. Now I am getting a weird error where it just runs over and over again inside the render() in an infinite loop but once I figure out what's wrong I will note this answer. If you have any ideas, I'm all ears

Comment: @bryan I know what is wrong. My mistake. I missed it. The sync functions runs inside the render and every time we set the state it runs again because component re-renders. If you move it to componentDidMount or some other appropriate place that would solve the problem

Comment: That fixed that issue! In my sync function, which is what I feared - I get the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: onChangeState`

Comment: @bryan this shouldn't be a problem if you used the same name as parameter on function declaration and inside of it. Please check your code for any typo and mismatch.

Comment: Just remember that the render function should be pure, never make async calls in render method. Good practice is to do this in componentDidMount

Comment: @bryan I am sure. It doesn't matter since you are sending function as a parameter. It should work. Please edit and add the last version of your code to the question as an update (don't delete the old part for reference purposes.)

Comment: Maybe you get this error because the fat arrow function syntax is experimental and your config file is not set to use it.

Comment: I forgot to send the onChangeState through the sync function and into the other function. No more error. Thanks so much for your help. I've learned a lot from this